# AngularJS - Internationalization in action

Tags: angularjs, date, angularjs-directive, internationalization

My goal is to change some "cultural things" like date format (e.g. IT: dd\mm\yyyy, GB: yyyy\mm\dd), time format (e.g. IT: 17:30, GB: 5.30PM), floating point | comma separator, ecc... in an AngularJS application. Me and a couple of work-mates came across i18n but reading the its documentation we couldn't figure how to use it. We spent a lot of time searching through many tutorials but they give too much thing for granted... quite unhelpful, right? :)

Could someone provide us some clear examples of i18n implementation (or any other way to do what explained above) in AngularJS, please?

Comment: What is unclear in the detailed instructions of the official documentation? What don't you understand? What is the concrete problem you're facing? https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/i18n

Comment: Sorry for late answer... I'd rather to understand how to use it practically with a simple example.